# Render a layout on button click in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: This is my drop down button]

I am using Rails to render a layout depending on what user has selected from this dropdown menu and I have no idea how may I render a layout from within link_to

```
eg:
 #main_div
    show feeds from : 
        %button.dropbtn{'onclick':'myfunc()'}
            Dropdown
            %span.caret
        #myDropdown.dropdown-content
            =link_to 'public'
            =link_to 'followers'
    =render 'progress'
```

in this the way I am rendering progress statically I want to render it on button click something like this :

```
  =link_to 'public' , render: 'progress'
```

One more problem is that even if this works I want layout to be rendered in another div (main div as of snippet ) not in link_to's div as you can see in code

Comment: You are duplicating your questions. Don't do that. Instead, remove one and incorporate the content of the two questions into the other. Asking twice is not good because it dilutes the quality of your question, and confuses those in the future who are searching for a similar solution.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that.

Comment: Now, can you help me with the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot render dynamically using Rails' layouts alone. Your simplest option is to render both partials in their own hidden divs:

```
#main_div
    show feeds from : 
        %button.dropbtn{'onclick':'myfunc()'}
        Dropdown
        %span.caret
    #myDropdown.dropdown-content
        =link_to 'public', onclick: 'showDiv("#public-content")'
        =link_to 'followers', onclick: 'showDiv("#followers-content")'
    #public-content
        =render 'progress_public'
    #followers-content
        =render 'progress_followers'
```

Then in CSS:

```
#public-content, #followers-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Then in JavaScript using jQuery:

```
function showDiv(divId) {
    $(divId).show();
}
```

If you don't want all partials rendered at once, you need to look into using AJAX calls to update part of the page dynamically.

Comment: I cannot show or hide them as partials are having infinite scrolling divs of users posts ... I thought about that but not possible. :/